# Python Jira How to detect the previous status of an issue

Tags: python, jira, jira-rest-api, python-jira

I'm currently using python and the jira api to automate certain events that happen on an issue.

Let say an issue was opened and then it gets closed. Then it gets re opened again for a second time.

When I look at the issue's history in the jira gui I can see that series of events.

If I use issue.fields.status in python I can only obtain the current status of the issue.

I want to trigger an action with python for when I search for an issue and that issue status changed from Closed status to Open status for a second time. In other words I want to trigger an action when an issue was reopened.

Do I have to fetch the history of the issue to do this? Is the only place where I see is getting tracked.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get the last status of an issue you will have to get it's history.

You can do that by execute GET function `https://your-jira-server.com/rest/api/2/issue/KEY?expand=backlog`

then loop over the history items from the response to search for the status.

```
   for item in history["items"]:
        if item["field"] == "status":
```